# Unable to save file on XLWings

Tags: python, xlwings

[USING XLWINGS PACKAGE]

I'm attempting to open an excel spreadsheet (existing), write data to specified cells, and then use the workbook.save() function to save the file to a new file name (as not to overwrite)

Right now I currently have:

```
app = xw.App(visible = False)
wbMain = wx.Book('Example.xlsm') #Open premade excel file
sheetMain = wbMain.sheets['Example']
sheetMain.range('A1').value = 'Test' #Modify value of cell A1
wbMain.save('NewFileName.xlsm') #Save to new filename
wbMain.close() #Close current excel sheet
app.kill() #Kill program (may not work)
```

(Sorry about my formatting if it's off)

Here is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test_proj\main.py", line 34, in <module>
wbMain.save(NewFileName.xlsm)
----
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
packages\xlwings\main.py", line 688, in save
return self.impl.save(path)
---
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 472, in save
self.xl.SaveAs(os.path.realpath(path))
----
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 63, in __call__
v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
---
File "<COMObject Open>", line 7, in SaveAs
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft 
Excel', 'SaveAs method of Workbook class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, 
-2146827284), None)
```

I've tried lookin at the XLWings documentation and various other stackoverflow threads but none seemed to offer a solution that worked. Has anyone had the same issue before?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - turns out using the **full path** in wbMain.save('C:/xxx/NewFileName.xlsm') worked for me.

Credits to @aneroid for the help! See here: [xlwings: Save and Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426763/xlwings-save-and-close?noredirect=1#comment93729402_53426763)